# Correct array_push usage in a class?

Tags: php, class, function, variables, array-push

I have a PHP class like so:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public $my_variable = array();

    public function func1() {
        $var1 = $this->my_variable;
        array_push($var1, 'var1');
        return $this->my_variable;
    }

    public function func2() {
        $var2 = $this->my_variable;
        array_push($var2, 'var2');
        return $this->my_variable;
    }
}

$my_class = new MyClass;

print_r($my_class->func1());
print_r($my_class->func2());
?>
```

The two `print_r` functions return an empty array, and there are no errors displayed.

How can I get the "var1" and "var2" strings added to the `$my_variable` array? I'm not sure where I am going wrong here...!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$var1 = $this->my_variable` actually creates a copy of the array, which you then push a value onto.

Instead, you can do this: `$var1 = &$this->my_variable` to create a reference instead, but it would just be better to not have the pointless variable at all:

```
public function func1() {
    $this->my_variable[] = 'var1';
    return $this->my_variable;
}
public function func2() {
    $this->my_variable[] = 'var2';
    return $this->my_variable;
}
```

Or, more appropriately:

```
public function add($value) {
    $this->my_variable[] = $value;
    return $this->my_variable;
}
// call with `$my_class->add('var1'); $my_class->add('var2');
```

Comment: @bwoebi: People interested in short code don't use `array_push`... :P

Comment: @minitech People who don't know about `[]` _use_ `array_push` ^^

Comment: I dont think I've ever used array_pop, ever, in 10ish years of writing php. But I also find that people who dont even know about array_push (regardless if they use it) also never know about array_pop and array_shift and array_unshift

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the `$var`'s by reference. You copy the array and then add to the copy some entry and then return the initial array.

```
$var2 = &$this->my_variable;
```

would be right. The `&` is marking here a reference.